# Salesforce Apex Test Coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, apex

Following is my Apex class:

```
public class lastViewed{

    public Datetime cDT; 
    public String LongDate; 
    public String firstname; 
    public String lastname;    
    public String userid;

    private final sObject dynObj;

    public lastViewed(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.dynObj = (sObject)stdController.getRecord();    
    }

    public String getLongDate() {        
        cDT = System.now();        //Format the datetime value to your locale        
        LongDate = cDT.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    return LongDate;    
    }


    private Boolean isLastViewedObjectExist(Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> orgMap)
    {
        if (orgMap.get('Myobject__c') != null )
        {
            return True;
        }
        else
        {
            return False;
        }
    }

    public void updateField() {
    //Get the user info from the current user        
    firstname = System.Userinfo.getFirstName();        
    lastname = System.Userinfo.getLastName();       
    userid = System.Userinfo.getUserId();


    //Assign values to Last Viewed By field &amp; update the record 
    Schema.SObjectType objObjectType = dynObj.getSObjectType();
    DescribeSObjectResult objDescribeResult;
    objDescribeResult = objObjectType.getDescribe();
    String strObjectName = objDescribeResult.getName();

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> orgMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    SObjectType objToken = orgMap.get(strObjectName);
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap(); 

    Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
    String nameField = '';
    for(String s:fieldSet)
    {
        SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(s);
        DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
        if (selectedField.isNameField())
        {
            System.debug(selectedField.getLabel());
            nameField = selectedField.getName();
        }
    }


    if (isLastViewedObjectExist(orgMap) == false)
    {
        System.debug('Myobject does not exist');
        return;
    }

    string strQuery = 'select ' +  nameField + ' from ' + strObjectName + ' where id = \'' + dynObj.id + '\' limit 1'; 
    System.debug(strQuery);
    sObject S = Database.query(strQuery);

    System.debug(nameField);
    String nameFieldValue = (String)S.get(nameField);

    Myobject__c viewObject = new Myobject__c (
    ObjectId__c = dynObj.id, 
    ObjectName__c = nameFieldValue,
    ViewedByName__c = firstname + ' ' + lastname,
    ViewedById__c = userid,
    ObjectType__c = strObjectName
    );

    insert viewObject;

    }
```

I wrote following test method for it, although it is a very small effort but code coverage percentage had no change and retained 0% value.

```
public static testMethod void myTestMethod() {
        Datetime cDT;
        String firstname;
        String lastname;
        String userid;
        Test.startTest();

        //Create account 
        Account a = new Account(Name='accountname');
        a.insert()

        cDT = System.now();        //Format the datetime value to your locale 
        System.assertEquals(cDT, System.now(), 'System now date is equal');

       Myobject__c obj = new Myobject__c(
           ObjectType__c = 'Account', ObjectId__c = '10', ObjectName__c = 'somename');
       System.debug('Name before inserting new fieldname: ' + obj.ObjectName__c);

       // Insert obj
       System.debug('Now inserting the obj..');
       insert obj;
       System.assertEquals('somename', obj.ObjectName__c);

       firstname = System.Userinfo.getFirstName();
       System.assertEquals(firstname, System.Userinfo.getFirstName(),'firstname is equal');
       lastname = System.Userinfo.getLastName();
       System.assertEquals(lastname, System.Userinfo.getLastName(), 'lastname is equal');
       userid = System.Userinfo.getUserId();
       System.assertEquals(userid, System.Userinfo.getUserId(), 'userid is equal');

       // stop test
       Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Please suggest me something onto how should I approach writing unit tests and achieve atleast 75% code coverage. Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Your test method should call the methods in the class lastViewed. As I could see so far your test method isn't calling any methods in the class lastViewd. And you have to run the test. You can use Developer Console to check which line hasn't yet been tested. Good luck!

Comment: Can you suggest how do I test updateField() method as it doesn't take any arguments in its method and only access the private object(dynObj) of lastViewed class.

Comment: You can get your code coverage by calling the method. And for test assertion, you can check whether viewObject was inserted. For example, select userid from Myobject__c and check if System.Userinfo.getUserId() is really put in there.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to test a controller extension's methods would be like this:

```
 Account a = new Account(name = 'foo');  // create the controller's object
 insert a;
 ApexPages.StandardController ctlr = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
 LastViewed ext = new LastViewed(ctlr);

 ext.updateField();   // invoke method on controller extension

 // fetch the object updated
 MyObject__c myObj = [select id, objectId__c, viewedbyname__c, ... from MyObject__c
                        where objectId__c = : a.id];
 // do assertions here to see if it was updated as you expect
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lw29 mentioned, you need to make sure that the methods of your class are invoked by the test. If you have a controller or a helper-class, you need to instantiate the class in the testmethod. Static functions has to be invoked, too.

If your methods will be called from an trigger, you may also have your code covered indirectly, when you use DML which fires the trigger in your tests.

Also make sure that you consider all possible logical flows. So if you have

```
if(condition == true) {
    i+=1;
} else {
    i+=2;
}
```

to get full coverage you have to invoke you code both ways to have condition == false as well as condition == true.

Comment: Thanks! calling methods worked to atleast get 19% test coverage. The question is how do I call updateField() method as it will be referencing a private object(dynObj) of lastViewed class. Placing @TestVisible keyword to the variable hasn't helped.

Comment: use if(test.isRunningTest()) { ... } to check if your method is called by a test. Inside it, you are in a test context. There try fake-create, fake-instantiate all you need with something. So you may not get 100% but way more than 19%.